# How to fit a table to the width of the page?

Tags: latex, tex, overleaf

Im trying to create a latex table using overleaf. How can I fit this table to be shown on one page? Attached is a picture that shows how my table is currently looking like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Summary Statistics and Sell in May Effect}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c}
\hline\hline 
 &  &  &  &  &  &  & t-Values of & t-Values of January\\ [0.5ex]
  &   &   &  &  &  &  & Adjusted Sell & Dummy with\\
    &  &  &  &  & & t-Values of Sell in & in May & Adjusted Sell\\
      &  &  & Mean &  &  & May Dummy & Dummy with & in May Dummy\\
     Country & Period & Observations & Return & Deviation & Alpha1 & (No January 
     Effect) & January Effect & in May Dummy\\
\hline
1 & 50 & 837 & 970 \\
2 & 47 & 877 & 230 \\
3 & 31 & 25 & 415 \\
4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
5 & 45 & 300 & 556 \\ [1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Current table]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use packages like `tabularx` or the new `tabularray` which allow the table to automatically adjust to the linewidth.

However you have sooooooooooo many columns that the result will look horrible. So in the example below, I also change the page geometry to get more space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[hmargin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Summary Statistics and Sell in May Effect}
\begin{tblr}{
  @{}ccccccX[c,valign=b]X[c,valign=b]X[c,valign=b]@{}
}
\hline
\hline
Country & 
Period  &  
Observations & 
Mean Return & 
Deviation & 
Alpha1 & 
t-Values of Sell in May Dummy (No January Effect) & 
t-Values of Adjusted Sell in May Dummy with January Effect & 
t-Values of January Dummy with Adjusted Sell in May Dummy\\
\hline
1 & 50 & 837 & 970 \\
2 & 47 & 877 & 230 \\
3 & 31 & 25 & 415 \\
4 & 35 & 144 & 2356 \\
5 & 45 & 300 & 556\\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]